# Regex: Want to change case of letter following one of a set, except HTML entity

Tags: java, regex

**Examples:**

```
rythm&blues                   -> Rythm&Blues  
.. DON&apos;T WEAR WHITE/LIVE -> Don&apos;t Wear White/Live
```

First I convert the whole string to lowercase (because I want to have only Uppercase at the start of a word).

I currently do this by using a split pattern: `[&/\\.\\s-]` 
And then I convert the parts' first letter to Uppercase.

It works well, except, that it also converts HTML entities of course:
E.g. `don&apos;t` is converted to `don&Apos;t` but that entity should be left alone.

While writing this I discover an additional problem... the initial conversion to lowercase potentially messes up some HTML entities as well. So, the entities should be totally left alone. (E.g. `&Ccedil;` is not the same as `&ccedil;`)

An HTML entity is probably matched like this: `&[a-z][A-Z][a-z]{1,5};`

I am thinking of doing something with groups, but unfortunately I find it very hard to figure out.

Comment: Do you have a list of entities that can be found in your data or it should take care of all possible entities?

Answer (score 2):

This pattern seems to handle your situation

```
"\\w+|&#?\\w+;\\w*"
```

There may be some edge cases, but we can adjust accordingly as they come up.

Pattern Breakdown:

- `\\w+` - Match any word
- `&#?\\w+;\\w*` - Match an HTML entity

Code Sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] lines = {
        "rythm&blues",
        ".. DON&apos;T WEAR WHITE/LIVE"
    };

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+|&#?\\w+;\\w*");
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lines[i]);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            if (matcher.group().startsWith("&")) {
                // Handle HTML entities 

                // There are letters after the semi-colon that 
                // need to be lower case
                if (!matcher.group().endsWith(";")) {
                    String htmlEntity = matcher.group();
                    int semicolonIndex = htmlEntity.indexOf(";");
                    lines[i] = lines[i].replace(htmlEntity,
                            htmlEntity.substring(0, semicolonIndex) +
                                    htmlEntity.substring(semicolonIndex + 1)
                                            .toLowerCase());
                }
            } else {
                // Uppercase the first letter of the word and lowercase
                // the rest of the word
                lines[i] = lines[i].replace(matcher.group(), 
                        Character.toUpperCase(matcher.group().charAt(0)) + 
                                matcher.group().substring(1).toLowerCase());
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lines));
}
```

Results:

```
[Rythm&Blues, .. Don&apos;t Wear White/Live]
```

Comment: 4th paragraph in the question specifically mentions that lowercasing the entire text is not acceptable. I also don't see how a group could (or should) start with `;` character. That said - good answer, I was starting to write something similar, and the problems should be easily fixable.

Comment: Oh, and HTML entities according to w3 can also be referred by `#NUMBER` instead of a name (like `&#60;`), regex should reflect that too.

Comment: Very happy with this solution. Works like a charm. I had to make a minor change: htmlEntity.substring(0, semicolonIndex) should be  htmlEntity.substring(0, semicolonIndex+1)

Comment: @dexter Glad to have helped.  Kindly click the check mark to my answer so your question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here will *probably* be lookahead assertions. That means a split should match `&` character only if it is not a start of entity. Problem here is that I am not sure whether your data can contain text, that can be mistakenly taken as an entity (basically any stuff ending with `;`). But let's assume for now it does not. This is how such split with negative lookahead pattern could look:

```
/(?!&apos;)[&/\.\s-]/
```

Note this is a case with only `&apos;` entity. You probably would like to extend possible entity list or provide pattern that matches all valid entities.